# Filter in dataframe based on array of values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have one array (name `df`) and dataframe (name `data`).

Array consists of unique id, say `df=array([10,11,12])`.

And dataframe consists of 3 columns: data, id, value.

I want to filter dataframe in such a way that it should only contain id specified in array

Answer (score 5):

IIUC:

```
data = data[data["id"].isin(df)]
```